# Looping through specific columns in two separate text files

Tags: python

I have two text files A and B, with 16 and 14 columns respectively.

The columns in these files are separated with spaces.

For each entry in column 9 of file A, I want to check if the entry is in column 8 of file B.

If it is, I would like to add this value to a new file (file C). However, I would like file C to retain the same format as file A.

In other words, this new file should contain 17 columns as well.

I have been unable to figure out how to approach this problem and cannot include my progress as a result. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the two files? How large are they?

Comment: soooooo, python matlab or bash?

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read both files into a list, extract B's 8th column in a list and then iterate over file A and check if its 9th element matches with the list of column 8 of B.

If there is a match then I am appending the match at end of each line of A else just print line A.

`NOTE:` if you do not need the line when there is no match then you can delete the `else` part.

Code

```
alines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('aa.txt')]
blines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('bb.txt')]

column8b=[]

for line in blines:
    column8b.append(line.split(" ")[7])

with open('cc.txt', "w") as oFile:
    for line in alines:
        element = line.split(" ")[8]
        if element in column8b:
            oFile.write(line + " " + element + "\n")
        ## Delete this if you do not want to write A into C
        ## when there is no match between A[9] and B[8]
        else:
            oFile.write(line + "\n")
```

Sample Data:

aa.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 16 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 26 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 36 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 46 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

bb.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 16 9 10 11 12 13 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 36 9 10 11 12 13 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

cc.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 16 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 26 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 36 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 36
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 46 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read in the file line by line, then you can pull out the relevant information you want.

```
your_file_A = open("FILEPATH.EXTENSION")
your_file_B = open("FILEPATH.EXTENSION")
your_file_C = open("FILEPATH.EXTENSION", 'w')
col8_of_B=[]
for line in your_file_B:
    col8_of_B.append(line[7]) #line[7] is position 8
for line in your_file_A:
    if line[8] in col8_of_B:
        your_file_C.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `awk` (since you have the `bash` tag)?:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {b[$8]=$0;next} b[$9] {print $0,$9 }' b a > c
```